# Bind an Option Button to 2 Fields / VBA to change a field based on Option Button

Tags: ms-access, vba

**What I have**

I have a form in which there is a section with 2 Option groups. The first option group has 3 values - 101, 102, and "None" which respectively return 101, 102, and 0 to the bound field. There is a second Option group underneath, that should only be filled when the first is not "None". That option group is also bound to a different field and has no default value.

**My question**

Is it possible to have the "None" OptionButton return 0 for both option groups? If not, it is probably possible if I un-bind the tables and do it all via VBA, which I have no problem with (and even prefer). I am not sure how, though - which VBA statement can update a field based on any criteria, be it group value or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the the first option group so that it has event code which will alter properties of the second option group.

So if the user changes option group 1 to be 101, or 102 the option group 2 controls have their "enabled" property set to true.  If the 1st is set to 0 then enabled is set to false AND ALSO the 2nd option group value is set to 0.

If you need more help with adding events and VBA let me know, but from what I can tell from your profile I think you will be able to take it from here.

You will ONLY need to write code in the After_Update event property of the 1st option group.  This code manages the second option group.

You should also set the default value of the 2nd option group to be 0.

Harvey

Comment: If the second option group has no option button with a value of 0, I can set the default to 0 anyways? Also, will disabling group 2 cause it to revert to its default value of 0?

Comment: No and No.  The second option button should have a value for 0 - even if it is a hidden option button the the user cannot chnage.  Consider: f the optional group value is stored in a field you might end up with non-0 values being stored when option group 1 has been set to 0.  So store 0 for option group 2 as a adefault just to make the data in the table clearer.

Comment: I ended up creating a GotFocus event on the first group that sets group 2 = 0 if None is selected! Works like a charm as far as I can tell.

Comment: Great, there's always many ways to get something done... That sounds elegant.  Can you tick my answer as an answer! Tahnks